# How to store videos in database?

Tags: database

What are the better ways to store videos or sequence of jpegs in the database. Whether it is better to store the path of uploaded videos in the file system or to store as blobs and why?

Comment: I reccomand you to store it as file and in the database store a link/path to the file location

Comment: If i store the video files on a web server hosted on a linux machine, concurrent access of same video files will slow down the system? or i need parallel file system (GFS), to store multiple video files, or any other special server side configuration needed?

Answer (score 1):

store files in databases is not recommend, this will slow db performance. if you have to do so, store it in blob.

Comment: store the path is better